# Subclassed component to the own tab in toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add my own component to the toolbox in visual studio 2015 but I want to use my own tabname, or if that's not possible the general tab, I guess I need to use reflection for that, but how ?

I wrote a subclassed component and I want to install this in the component toolbox, this component appears in the "All Windows forms" tab, but I want to install it in my own tab like "myComponents"

Comment: You can just right-click a tab to rename it, or create a new one and enter the name yourself, or is that not what you mean? Are you writing a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: S/he might mean the category, but not sure about these Tabs in VS2015